# docker is full, all inodes are used

Tags: docker

got huge problem, all my inodes seems to be used.
I've cleaned all volumes unused 
Cleaned all container and images
with command -> docker prune

but still it seems that it stay full :

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
none           3200000 3198742   1258  100% /
tmpfs           873942      16 873926    1% /dev
tmpfs           873942      13 873929    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      3200000 3198742   1258  100% /images
shm             873942       1 873941    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           873942       1 873941    1% /sys/firmware
```

docker info

```
Containers: 5
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 23
Server Version: 17.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 53
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170
runc version: 810190ceaa507aa2727d7ae6f4790c76ec150bd2
init version: 949e6fa
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 6.668GiB
Name: serveur-1
ID: CW7J:FJAH:S4GR:4CGD:ZRWI:EDBY:AYBX:H2SD:TWZO:STZU:GSCX:TRIC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

The only thing i think can do this, is a build i'm doing on this machine.
This build runs a npm install with many files. 
Can these files stays on server ? 
is there any chance i have to delete these temporary files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the error, 
this seems to be Docker 17.06.1-ce error. 
This version seems not correctly deleting images, and keeping files in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/`
So just upgrade to new docker version and this will be fine.
now df show me

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       51558236 3821696  45595452   8% /
udev               10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs            1398308   57696   1340612   5% /run
tmpfs            3495768       0   3495768   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            3495768       0   3495768   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

This is better :)

Comment: I had to delete the empty directories with: `rmdir /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/*`. That way, I could free up some inodes (listed with: `df -i`)

Comment: After I completed [apt-get upgrade docker], I found that docker has automatically helped me to clear the redundant Inodes automatically. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 8):

Is there any dangling volumes left in the system? If you have dangling volumes, it may fill up your disk space.

List all dangling volumes

```
docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true
```

Remove all dangling volumes

```
docker volume rm `docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true`
```

Comment: i saw that this version of docker is sometimes doing it, i upgrade to last version and will look at this. Thanks
(normally all my volumes are ok, but will look again)

Comment: just before upgrading, i saw that this folder /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ was full. Seems that when i delete images, this is not really deleting them. Am i right ?

Comment: It looks like dangling volumes. Consider these as volume mounted into the container but is in dangling state. Deleting images and removing containers won't delete these volumes. Did you happen to run the above command before upgrading?

Comment: i had already removed them yes, just did nothing more on space used. Seems that was a bug on this specific version of docker (found it on their github)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Had Jenkins running inside Docker with a volume attached to it. After a few weeks Jenkins told me "npm WARN tar ENOSPC: no space left on device". After some googling I found out that all inodes are taken with `sudo df -ih`. With `sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` I could locate the folder using up all the inodes and it was a certain build with npm. Deleted that folder and now I'm good to go again.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be an effect of a lot of stopped containers, for example if there's a cron job running that use a container, and the `docker run` commandline used does not include `--rm` - in that case, every cron invocation will leave a stopped container on the filesystem.

In this case, the output of `docker info` will show a high number under Server -> Containers -> Stopped.

To cure this:

1. `docker container prune`
2. Add `--rm` to your `docker run` command line in the cron job.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with `docker builder prune` which clears the build cache and nothing else. (Thanks @Maestro)

In my case it was `dangling build cache` because removing dangling images does not solve the issue.

This cache can be removed by following command: `docker system prune --all --force`, but be careful maybe you still need some volumes or images.

Comment: Its better to use ```docker builder prune``` because it only clears the build cache and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, pods with ingress-nginx and modsecurity active are creating a lot of dirs & files on container volumes in mod security structure (/var/lib/docker/overlay2/...) after more than 80 days of execution.

Restarting the pods remove the problem.

This case can be generalize to other cases with container internal storage no controlled

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).