# Docker containers consuming all the inodes of linux machine

Tags: linux, docker, inode

I am running out of inodes on my Debian 10 machine
I found the culprits

```
~# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            500578     317 500261    1% /dev
tmpfs           504337     547 503790    1% /run
/dev/sda1      3276800 3090639 186161   95% /
tmpfs           504337       1 504336    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           504337       3 504334    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           504337      17 504320    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
overlay        3276800 3090639 186161   95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c238a2f5bcd5e7e193d572fd4b331510cd2438d113a66e9125f983c929cd8485/merged
overlay        3276800 3090639 186161   95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5f3ee0ad57f147f8dba95e1e06ea98fc697c72ff8eaaafa6494faeb8f0742096/merged
tmpfs           504337      11 504326    1% /run/user/10976
tmpfs           504337      11 504326    1% /run/user/10762
shm             504337       1 504336    1% /var/lib/docker/containers/135852b9e95d22ace0cf10b27752a3ad15d1fdfaebcde74f546c26ae4ef01ad8/mounts/shm
shm             504337       1 504336    1% /var/lib/docker/containers/cd9619f7703b1e9fee7c1338379dab5270260d23834b27f278c57500b5e50b5a/mounts/shm
```

docker overlay `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/*/merged`
Only 2 containers are running.
no dangling images on the machine as well.

```
~# docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 19
Server Version: 20.10.18
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
 userxattr: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
init version: de40ad0
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 5.7.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.848GiB
Name: name
ID: SNF2:X4SU:OLKG:ESHV:PX3U:UJGB:MADV:OZ3R:UCZP:KONV:K4ZV:ILL4
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

what can I do to reclaim inodes?

PS: `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

`docker system prune` and `docker image prune` does not help either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker is full, all inodes are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531597/docker-is-full-all-inodes-are-used)

Comment: Can you try to find out which directories contains most files ? `find / > /tmp/files.list`

Comment: @GauravPathak No, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: @Philippe top 3 `131936 /var/lib/docker/overlay2`
 `65931 /var/lib/docker/containers`
 `19769 /opt/Dev...`

Comment: How many files are there in `/var/lib/docker` ? If it's far from 3000000, then docker may not be culprit.